# Chekbox, чтобы включать и выключать input

Tags: html, css, input

Как сделать такое дополнение к `input` в виде `checkbox`, чтобы он выключал и включал `input`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос [mcve]. Как без кода понять, что и куда нужно добавлять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример решения c использованием jQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/tj9v02fk/

```js
$(".button").on("change", function() {
  if ($('.button').is(':checked')) {
    $(".text-box").removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $(".text-box").attr('disabled', true);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="checkbox" class="button" id="button">
  <label for="button"></label>
  <input type="text" class="text-box" disabled="disabled">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Оба элемента помещаем в `div` и позиционируем абсолютно. Как-то так:

```js
$(".check").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(".text").attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $(".text").attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <input type="text" class="text">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```